# Unicode Error while loading data from csv to Greenplum

Tags: csv, unicode, greenplum

I have a csv file and need to load it to Greenplum DB.
My code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usr_wrk.CAR(
brand varchar(255),
model varchar(255),
ID    INTEGER
);

COPY usr_wrk.CAR FROM '...Car.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

But I get this error:

```
[22025] ERROR: invalid Unicode escape: Unicode escapes must be full-length: \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX.
```

Rows of a csv file looks, for example, like:

Jaguar,XJ,1

Or

Citroen,C4,91

I replaced all non-latin words, there are no NULL or empty values, but it still appears. Does anybody have thoughts on this?

P.S.

I don't have admin rights and can make/drop and rule tables only in this schema.

Answer (score 1):

You might try one of the following:

copy usr_wrk.car from .../Car.csv DELIMITER ',' **ESCAPE as 'OFF' NULL as ''** CSV HEADER;

OR

copy usr_wrk.car from .../Car.csv DELIMITER ',' **ESCAPE as '\' NULL as ''** CSV HEADER;

Default escape is a double quote for CSV format.  Turning it off or setting it to the default TEXT format escape (a backslash) may get you around this.   You could also remove the CSV header from the file and declare it as TEXT file with a comma delimiter to avoid having to specify the ESCAPE character.

Are you sure there are no special characters around the car names?   Thinking specifically of umlauts or grave accents that would make the data multibyte and trigger that error.

You might try doing:  head Car.csv | oc -c | more   and see if any multibyte characters show up in your file (this assumes you are on a Linux system).

If it is possible for you to do, you might try using the GPLOAD utility to load the file.   You can specify the ENCODING of the data file as 'LATIN1' which may get you past the UTF error you are hitting.

Hope this helps.
Jim